# X3DOM - Layer image on only one side of box

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I am following the example to add a texture (image), and need it to only be on one side of a box, but the example wraps it around all sides. The tutorial is here:

http://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/basics/imagesMovies/index.html

I am also using an external file via the inline option. How can I get an image to only overlay on a desired side of a box instead of all sides?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to create your box using the indexedfaceset node. Then you can apply the image textures to each face independently. There's an example here: http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/Basic/DistributedInteractiveSimulation/TestCube.x3d

Comment: Do you have an example that actually explains how to use the indexedfaceset node?